# Backwards in time...Zelazny?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Maybe it's not Zelazny...  A man has a fight with his partner; she angrily rushes out the door, dies tragically in a car crash.  He is inconsolable.  Gradually, he starts to notice time moves backwards in little spurts.  He pursues it and eventually is able to move time back to just before the fight.  It's killing me!  thx;   Peter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

["Divine Madness"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44007), a short story by [Roger Zelazny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Zelazny); first published in [*Magazine of Horror*, Summer 1966](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59488+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/MagazineOfHorror13V03n011966Summer#page/n29/mode/2up). Does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?44007) look familiar?

Excerpts:

> He blew smoke through the cigarette and it grew longer.
>
> He glanced at the clock and realized that its hands were moving backwards.
>
> Then came the thing like despair, for he knew there was not a thing he could do about it. He was trapped, moving in reverse through the sequence of actions past. Somehow, he had missed the warning.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> The door slammed open.
>
> She stared in at him, her mascara smeared, tears upon her cheeks.
>
> "!hell to go Then," he said.
>
> "!going I'm," she said.
>
> She stepped back inside, closed the door.
>
> She hung her coat hurriedly in the hall closet.
>
> ".it about feel you way the that's If," he said shrugging.
>
> "!yourself but anybody about care don't You," she said.
>
> "!child a like behaving You're," he said.
>
> "!sorry you're say least at could You"
>
> Her eyes flashed like emeralds through the pink static, and she was lovely and alive again. In his mind he was dancing.
>
> The change came.
>
> "You could at least say you're sorry!"
>
> "I am," he said, taking her hand in a grip that she could not break. "How much, you'll never know."
>
> "Come here." And she did.