# A short story where a man experiences time reversal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

A man experiences the reversal of time of the last few days where he relives an argument with his wife which leads to her death and he corrects it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I know I've read this one.  Car accident, right?  How long ago did you read it?  I'm thinking Zelazny or Saberhagen, but that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't know if that's the one HE was thinking of, but it's for sure the one I was thinking of.

Comment: Agree, Divine Madness.

Comment: @Gregg Koski: If they are correct, you can accept user14111's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 10):

["Divine Madness"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44007), a short story by [Roger Zelazny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Zelazny); first published in [*Magazine of Horror*, Summer 1966](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59488+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/MagazineOfHorror13V03n011966Summer#page/n29/mode/2up); also the answer to the question [Backwards in time...Zelazny?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171489/backwards-in-time-zelazny). Does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?44007) look familiar?

**A man experiences the reversal of time of the last few days**

> He blew smoke through the cigarette and it grew longer.
>
> He glanced at the clock and realized that its hands were moving backwards.
>
> Then came the thing like despair, for he knew there was not a thing he could do about it. He was trapped, moving in reverse through the sequence of actions past. Somehow, he had missed the warning.
>
> Usually, there was a prism-effect, a flash of pink static, a drowsiness, then a moment of heightened perception . . .

**where he relives an argument with his wife which leads to her death**

> She was dead.
>
> She was lying somewhere in the fragments of her car on Interstate 90 now.
>
> As he paced, unsmoking, he knew she was lying there bleeding.
>
> . . . Then dying, after that crash at eighty miles an hour.
>
> . . . Then alive?
>
> Then re-formed, along with the car, and alive again, arisen? Even now backing home at a terrible speed, to re-slam the door on their final argument? To unscream at him and be unscreamed at?

**and he corrects it.**

> The door slammed open.
>
> She stared in at him, her mascara smeared, tears upon her cheeks.
>
> "!hell to go Then," he said.
>
> "!going I'm," she said.
>
> She stepped back inside, closed the door.
>
> She hung her coat hurriedly in the hall closet.
>
> ".it about feel you way the that's If," he said shrugging.
>
> "!yourself but anybody about care don't You," she said.
>
> "!child a like behaving You're," he said.
>
> "!sorry you're say least at could You"
>
> Her eyes flashed like emeralds through the pink static, and she was lovely and alive again. In his mind he was dancing.
>
> The change came.
>
> "You could at least say you're sorry!"
>
> "I am," he said, taking her hand in a grip that she could not break. "How much, you'll never know."
>
> "Come here." And she did.